# Add remote subscriber SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

I am getting this error:

> SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a connection to the server. Specify the actual server name, 'Bla'. (Replication.Utilities)

I am aware of this:

http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/sqlserver/replication_requires_actual_server_name.htm

and I have applied it. Unfortunately, the error persists. How can I add a remote subscribers with either an IP or DNS name?

PS:

[This](http://www.travisgan.com/2015/06/sql-replication-subscriber-on-different.html) seems to help.

Comment: How "remote" subscriber is? Is it accessible from your local network?

Comment: yes via its ip + dns entry. I managed to get further with this see PS but get: "the selected Subscriber does not satisfy the minimum version compatibility level of the selected publication" This is also discussed here: http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2013/07/the-selected-subscriber-does-not.html providing a potential solution

Comment: ok, it looks like you are one step away from the goal

Comment: the publisher is ss 2012 whereas the target is ss 2014. bit strange that I have to use a different version o ssms to overcome: "the selected Subscriber does not satisfy the minimum version compatibility level of the selected publication"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to do this:

1. Create aliases publisher side as described [here](http://www.travisgan.com/2015/06/sql-replication-subscriber-on-different.html)
2. As my publisher is sql server 2012 and my subscriber sql server 2014 I had to use SSMS 2014 publisher side as described [here](http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2013/07/the-selected-subscriber-does-not.html).